# Arduino WiFi shield stop working at WiFi.status()

Tags: arduino

UPDATE:
I pinpointed where the problem is coming from. To avoid any complication, I'm using ScanNetwork example, so I don't even have to put in `SSID`. The code stops functioning on the board as soon as it hits `WiFi.status()`.
I have a `Serial.println` before and after it tries to get a `WiFi.status()`, the `serial.println` after wasn't performed, and of course, I'm still not connected.

I've downloaded fresh copy of the code, and the situation remains the same. I've really run out of idea....

---

I'm using the official arduino wifi shield, and I have the following code:

```
status = WiFi.begin([ssid],[pass]);
Serial.println(status);
```

Status is neither `WL_CONNECTED` nor `WL_IDLE_STATUS`, which are the two possible responses outlined in the official reference http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiBegin

Status is the number 4.
and of course, I couldn't connect to wifi.
What is this????

I've pressed the reset button a million times, is there a more powerful factory restore button?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I've figured it out.
Apparently, there's a jumper, that when you put it in, it'll kick the shield into a DFU-mode that enables reprogramming. And the shield wouldn't be present as a result.

Answer (score 2):

According to [WiFi.h](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/WiFi.h) The return values of the `begin()` functions (all three of them, one for each security scheme) are `int`s. It is not stated outright on this function but I believe that just as with the `status()` function the return type is a `wl_status_t`. `wl_status_t` is an enum declared in [wl_definitions.h](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/utility/wl_definitions.h) As:

```
typedef enum {
        WL_NO_SHIELD = 255,
        WL_IDLE_STATUS = 0,
        WL_NO_SSID_AVAIL,
        WL_SCAN_COMPLETED,
        WL_CONNECTED,
        WL_CONNECT_FAILED,
        WL_CONNECTION_LOST,
        WL_DISCONNECTED
} wl_status_t;
```

So your `4` is `WL_CONNECT_FAILED`. Probably not surprising to you since, you know, you connection failed.

The hobbiest's debugger, AKA reset button, will only do so much. Printing the status was a good start. Be sure you are using the right flavor of `begin()` for you security type, you seem to be using the one for WPA. Consider shutting off you router's security completely (if safe to do so in your area), or using a spare router, to test the ability of the shield to communicate at all. Also this may sound obvious but check for a misspelling of the SSID.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your comment, I've pinpoint the problem. The code comes to a complete stop as soon as it hits WiFi.status(), please see update above.

Comment: This very-well might be an error on your shield. Try updating the firmware on the shield. [The how-to for that can be found on **this** page of the arduino.cc website.](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/WiFiShieldFirmwareUpgrading)

Comment: I was reading it and got stuck on the part it mentions "Connect the J3 jumper to put the shield in the programming mode" what's a J3 jumper